# Create new related object when updating one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't figure out how to create new related object when I update my User instance. Here'are my models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Email'))

class Weight(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    units = models.IntegerField(choices=UNITS)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    weight = WeightSerializer(source='weight')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'weight')

class WeightSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Weight
        fields = ('value', 'units',)
```

Here's the actual view:

```
class UserDetails(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
```

I need to create new Weight object every time I update User info. How can I do that? When I'm trying to do it now, I get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: I see you're using Django REST Framework 2.x, I'd recommend updating to 3.x if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Django REST Framework 3.0**, serializers must explicitly handle nested updates, which is essentially what you are trying to do here. You would just need to override `perform_update` and have it create the new `Weight` object instead of manually updating it.

**In Django REST Framework 2.4**, much of this happens *automagically*, and you are trying to change that magic behavior.

Django will do an update on a model object if the object has an `id` on it, and an update if `id` is set to `None`. This means that you can create a basic copy of the object by setting the `id` to `None`, which is the easiest way to do what you are looking for right now.

```
class UserDetails(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user.weight.pk = None
                user.weight.save()
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
```

This should cause a new `Weight` object to be created each time the user is updated.